# Combining functions in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Please see my image,

[image]

I am need to count number of rows that have the cell value (in G column) = 1; but the values of column A and column B not equal another rows (not loop). For example: Row 4 have A4 = A3 = 16 and B4= B3 = 221 so we ignore (Row 6 is ignore, too).

Do you know what is the proper function ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your image, use this one in `I1` and drag it down:

```
=IF(AND(G1=1,COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1,$A1,$B$1:$B1,$B1)=1),"YES","NO")
```

and then in `I8` you can use

```
=COUNTIF(I1:I6,"YES")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do something like this, where you can add as many other conditionals as you need to the AND function.

```
=IF(AND(G4=1, NOT(A4=A3), NOT(B4=B3)),"True","False")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble following the logic in your question - the best solution is likely to write a custom VBA function and then call that function per cell. See www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx